# How to set a value for entity field in a form? Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have 3 tables realated, inProducto, inProveedor and InProveedorProducto, here my relashionship:

inProveedorProducto:

```
class InProveedorProducto
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InProducto", inversedBy="InProveedorProducto")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_producto", referencedColumnName="id_producto")
     */
    protected $producto;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InProveedor", inversedBy="InProveedorProducto")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_proveedor", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $proveedor;
```

InProveedor:

```
class InProveedor
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InProveedorProducto", mappedBy="InProveedor", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $proveedorProducto;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->proveedorProducto = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

And InProducto:

```
class InProducto
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InProveedorProducto", mappedBy="InProducto", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $producto;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->producto = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

My problem is that I have to open a new Form for inProveedorProducto, but idProveedor field should be automatic from prior selection of user.

My controller:

```
   public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new InProveedorProducto();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        $form->get('idProveedor')->setData(1);

        return $this->render('NivalInventarioBundle:InProveedorProducto:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

When I open de form, the first field which is idProveedor appears filled out with the number 1.

THen we select the idProducto and put the price, but when try to create:

Error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO in_proveedor_producto (id_proveedor, id_producto, precio_compra) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, 21, 1]:
```

It seems like idProveedor is comming NULL.

My inProveedorProducto type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('idProveedor')
            ->add('producto', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'NivalInventarioBundle:InProducto',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.nombre', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'nombre',
                'by_reference' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una opción',
                'mapped' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            ))
            ->add('precioCompra')
        ;
```

Please help me.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operate with a model, not with a form data.

```
   public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new InProveedorProducto();
        $entity->setProveedor($this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('NivalInventarioBundle:InProveedor')->find(1));
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return $this->render('NivalInventarioBundle:InProveedorProducto:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

And then just

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('proveedor')
            ->add('producto')
            ->add('precioCompra')
        ;
```

Comment: I changed the code, but I get this error:
"Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Nival\InventarioBundle\Entity\InProveedor could not be converted to string"

Comment: Just add a method __toString() to your InProveedor class. It should return some most significant field you need (f.e name)